# Al restar meses con JavaScript en Chrome, Firefox o Edge, los resultados son erróneos con ciertos meses

Tags: javascript, date

Estoy intentando restar un mes a una fecha. El código empleado sería el siguiente:

```js
var midia = new Date("08/31/2022");
midia.setMonth(midia.getMonth() - 1);
console.info(midia);
```

Me ocurre una cosa muy curiosa los días 31 (30 y 29 de febrero también): en los meses de Marzo, Mayo, Julio, Diciembre, funciona mal y no me resta un mes, en cambio en Enero, Agosto y Octubre, sí.
Creo que es un bug, no sé si del intérprete de Chrome, Firefox o Edge de JavaScript o del propio JavaScript.
Supongo que el problema es que cuando llega al día 31 de un mes que no tiene tantos días aparece el error, es decir que resta mal y el resultado de restar un mes a un `31/03/2022` es `03/03/2022`, cuando debería ser `28/02/2022`.
¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Cálculo mental rápido: si febrero tiene 28 días (el caso de este año), y marzo tiene 31 días, devuelve 3 de marzo: 28 (días de febrero) + 3 (días que "le faltan" a febrero). ¡Buena pregunta! ¿Cuál sería el resultado esperado, en ese caso?

Comment: Es muy buena la pregunta... el tema es que `Javascript` resta el mes y suma los días excedentes. En tu caso ¿estas buscando el primer día del mes anterior? ¿a cuantos días es equivalente un mes? Por que si de días estamos hablando, no hay la misma cantidad de días entre `01/02/2022 - 01/03/2022` y entre `28/02/2022-31/03/2022`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bien, *no es un bug, es un feature* ;)

De hecho, al revisar la [documentación de `setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth), se da una clara advertencia (énfasis mío):

> El día actual del mes tendrá un impacto en el comportamiento de este método. Conceptualmente agregará el número de días dados por el día actual del mes al primer día del nuevo mes especificado como parámetro, para devolver la nueva fecha. Por ejemplo, **si el valor actual es el 31 de agosto de 2016, llamar a setMonth con un valor de 1 devolverá el 2 de marzo de 2016. Esto se debe a que en febrero de 2016 tuvo 29 días.**

e incluso se da un ejemplo:

```js
//Cuidado con las transiciones de fin de mes
var endOfMonth = new Date(2016, 7, 31);
endOfMonth.setMonth(1);
console.log(endOfMonth); //Wed Mar 02 2016 00:00:00
```

Téngase en cuenta que `setMonth()` es *index-based* (basado en índice), es decir que los meses, según esta función, empiezan en 0.

En cuanto a la solución, *eso dependerá de lo que consideres qué es un mes* (tal como menciona @gilly3 en [su respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937257) en el sitio en inglés).

Tal usuario daba un ejemplo de lo que se podría hacer **en este caso particular** (ver último comentario en el código), devolviendo el último día del mes anterior:

```js
//código adaptado en base a https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937257

function modificarMes(fechaOrigen, meses){
  const fecha = new Date(fechaOrigen); //¡se hace esto para no modificar la fecha original!
  const mes = fecha.getMonth();
  fecha.setMonth(fecha.getMonth() + meses);
  while (fecha.getMonth() === mes) {
      fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() - 1);
  }
  return fecha;
}

const fechaInicial = new Date("03/31/2022");
console.log(fechaInicial.toLocaleDateString()); //31/03/2022

//ojo: a partir del cuarto mes, de nuevo devuelve resultados "inesperados":
console.log(modificarMes(fechaInicial, -1).toLocaleDateString()); // 28/02/2022
console.log(modificarMes(fechaInicial, -2).toLocaleDateString()); // 31/01/2021
console.log(modificarMes(fechaInicial, -3).toLocaleDateString()); // 31/12/2021
console.log(modificarMes(fechaInicial, -4).toLocaleDateString()); // 01/12/2021 !!!
console.log(modificarMes(fechaInicial, -5).toLocaleDateString()); // 31/10/2021
console.log(modificarMes(fechaInicial, -6).toLocaleDateString()); // 01/10/2021 !!!
```

Otra solución propuesta fue la [hecha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54452875) por @N8allan también en el sitio en inglés. Creó una función en donde se pasa una fecha (donde el parámetro de mes es el mes + 1), la cual retorna una nueva fecha cuyo día se estableció con [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min). Este código fue adaptado para que solo reciba la fecha y la cantidad de meses a restar como parámetros:

```js
//código adaptado en base a https://stackoverflow.com/a/54452875

function deltaDate(fecha, meses) {
    return new Date(
      fecha.getFullYear(),
      fecha.getMonth() + meses,
      Math.min(
        fecha.getDate(),
        new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth() + meses + 1, 0).getDate()
      )
    );
}

//¡es 31 de marzo!
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2022, 2, 31), -1).toLocaleDateString()); //28/02/2022
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2022, 2, 31), -2).toLocaleDateString()); //31/01/2022
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2022, 2, 31), -3).toLocaleDateString()); //31/12/2021
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2022, 2, 31), -4).toLocaleDateString()); //30/11/2021
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2022, 2, 31), -5).toLocaleDateString()); //31/10/2021
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2022, 2, 31), -6).toLocaleDateString()); //30/09/2021

// Ahora, con años bisiestos:
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2020, 2, 31), -1).toLocaleDateString()); //29/02/2020
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2020, 2, 31), -2).toLocaleDateString()); //31/01/2020
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2020, 2, 31), -3).toLocaleDateString()); //31/12/2019
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2020, 2, 31), -4).toLocaleDateString()); //30/11/2019
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2020, 2, 31), -5).toLocaleDateString()); //31/10/2019
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2020, 2, 31), -6).toLocaleDateString()); //30/09/2019

// PARECE funcionar :)
```

> Cabe aclarar que no se han hecho pruebas con días que no sean fines de mes.

Por último, y de nuevo, se insiste: ***todo dependerá de lo que consideres qué es un mes***.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, la verdad es que no hay nada como leerse la documentación.... Para otra vez lo tendré en cuenta. Me ha servido de gran ayuda, pensaba que era un error, pero como tu bien dices es una características. Has sido super rápido en contestar, esta comunidad es una pasada.

Answer (score 2):

Hola, entiendo que lo que quieres es que si ponemos por fecha el 31/03/2022 te devuelva el 28/02/2022 y si ponemos el 28/03/2022 te devuelva el 28/02/2022, es decir el mismo día pero del mes anterior y si el mismo día no puede ser porque el mes anterior no tiene ese día, el último día de ese mes. 
Para lo que quieres, no puedes utilizar `setMonth()` porque si restas uno al mes de por ejemplo el 31/3/2022 el resultado sería 31/02/2022 y como eso no puede ser, la función coge el 28/02/2022 y le añade los 3 días que le sobran, por tanto devuelve el 3/03/2022.
También ten en cuenta que las fechas se guardan siempre en la zona horaria UTC (o GMT), así que si haces un `console.log(fecha);`, la verás en esa zona horaria y si por ejemplo en España que tenemos una zona horaria de GMT+1 le asignas una fecha de forma `var midia = new Date("1/1/2022");`, le estás diciendo que en la hora local es el 1/1/2022 a las 00:00 horas, pero si imprimes en la consola la variable, verías el 31/12/2021 a las 23:00, en cambio si imprimes `midia.getFullYear()` te estaría devolviendo el 2022 porque siempre devuelve los datos en hora local. Para ver la fecha en formato local, deberías usar por ejemplo `console.log(midia.toLocaleDateString());` entonces sí verías el 1/1/2022. 
Dicho esto para conseguir lo que tu quieres, debes restar el mes teniendo en cuenta el último día del mes anterior. Para ello puedes crear un método nuevo para la clase Date que te devuelva la fecha como tú la necesitas. Sería algo así:

```
Date.prototype.MesAnterior = function() {
    var mes = this.getMonth();
    var year = this.getFullYear();
    var dia = this.getDate();
    var ultimoDia = new Date(year, mes, 0);
    if (mes === 0) {
        mes = 11;
        year = year - 1;
    } else {
        mes = mes - 1;
    }
    if (dia > ultimoDia.getDate()) {
        dia = ultimoDia.getDate();
    }
    var fecha = new Date(year, mes, dia);
    return fecha;
};
```

Primero obtenemos las variables para el dia, mes y año de la fecha, a continuación creamos una nueva variable de tipo Date con el mismo año y mes pero con el día 0, esto nos creará una fecha con el último día del mes anterior. Ahora comparamos el mes, si es 0 (enero), lo ponemos a 11 (Diciembre) y le quitamos 1 al año, en caso contrario restamos 1 al mes. Después comprobamos que el día del mes no sea mayor que el último día del mes anterior, si es así, tomamos este como el día. Sólo nos queda formar la nueva fecha y devolverla. Ahora utilizando el método `fecha.MesAnterior()` tendremos la fecha tal y como la quieres. Te dejo un ejemplo ejecutable con varias fechas. Un saludo.

```js
Date.prototype.MesAnterior = function() {
    var mes = this.getMonth();
    var year = this.getFullYear();
    var dia = this.getDate();
    var ultimoDia = new Date(year, mes, 0);
    if (mes === 0) {
        mes = 11;
        year = year - 1;
    } else {
        mes = mes - 1;
    }
    if (dia > ultimoDia.getDate()) {
        dia = ultimoDia.getDate();
    }
    var fecha = new Date(year, mes, dia);
    return fecha;
};
var midia = new Date("1/1/2022");
console.log("Para la fecha: " + midia.toLocaleDateString() + " el resultado es: " + midia.MesAnterior().toLocaleDateString());
var midia = new Date("2/28/2022");
console.log("Para la fecha: " + midia.toLocaleDateString() + " el resultado es: " + midia.MesAnterior().toLocaleDateString());
var midia = new Date("3/31/2022");
console.log("Para la fecha: " + midia.toLocaleDateString() + " el resultado es: " + midia.MesAnterior().toLocaleDateString());
var midia = new Date("3/31/2020");
console.log("Para la fecha: " + midia.toLocaleDateString() + " el resultado es: " + midia.MesAnterior().toLocaleDateString());
var midia = new Date("3/29/2022");
console.log("Para la fecha: " + midia.toLocaleDateString() + " el resultado es: " + midia.MesAnterior().toLocaleDateString());
var midia = new Date("3/28/2022");
console.log("Para la fecha: " + midia.toLocaleDateString() + " el resultado es: " + midia.MesAnterior().toLocaleDateString());
var midia = new Date("3/27/2022");
console.log("Para la fecha: " + midia.toLocaleDateString() + " el resultado es: " + midia.MesAnterior().toLocaleDateString());
var midia = new Date("8/31/2022");
console.log("Para la fecha: " + midia.toLocaleDateString() + " el resultado es: " + midia.MesAnterior().toLocaleDateString());
var midia = new Date("12/31/2022");
console.log("Para la fecha: " + midia.toLocaleDateString() + " el resultado es: " + midia.MesAnterior().toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: Muchisimas por tu respuesta, me ha servido mucho para ampliar conocimientos, gracias por tu rapidez y tu atención.